# C++: declaring enumerator within class from outside so can be used in private members

Tags: c++, enums

```
class Printer;
enum Printer::States;
class Printer {                  // choose one of monitor or cormonitor
    States taskStates[];
  public:
    enum States { Starting = 'S', Blocked = 'B', Unblocked = 'U', Finished = 'F', // general
          Napping = 'N', Awake = 'A',             // Santa
          Working = 'W', NeedHelp = 'H',          // elf
          OnVacation = 'V', CheckingIn = 'I',     // reindeer
          DeliveringToys = 'D', DoneDelivering = 'd', // Santa, reindeer
          Consulting = 'C', DoneConsulting = 'c' // Santa, elves
    };
    Printer();
    void print( unsigned int id, States state );
    void print( unsigned int id, States state, unsigned int numBlocked );
};
```

Comment: Or you could just make a private section after the `enum` is declared and put it in that...

Comment: Are you asking how/where to define `States`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare nested enums outside of the class. You also have to have it be defined before you use it.

```
class Printer {                  // choose one of monitor or cormonitor
  public:
    enum States { Starting = 'S', Blocked = 'B', Unblocked = 'U', Finished = 'F', // general
      Napping = 'N', Awake = 'A',             // Santa
      Working = 'W', NeedHelp = 'H',          // elf
      OnVacation = 'V', CheckingIn = 'I',     // reindeer
      DeliveringToys = 'D', DoneDelivering = 'd', // Santa, reindeer
      Consulting = 'C', DoneConsulting = 'c' // Santa, elves
    };
  private:
    States taskStates[];
  public:
    Printer();
    void print( unsigned int id, States state );
    void print( unsigned int id, States state, unsigned int numBlocked );
};
```

As a side-note, C++11's `enum class` only has to be declared inside the class - it can be defined outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to forward-declare an enumeration. In C++03 this is illegal. In C++11, you can do this as long as you specify the underlying type of the enum. From wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations

```
enum Enum1;                      // Illegal in C++03 and C++11; the underlying type cannot be determined.
enum Enum2 : unsigned int;       // Legal in C++11, the underlying type is explicitly specified.
enum class Enum3;                // Legal in C++11, the underlying type is int.
enum class Enum4 : unsigned int; // Legal C++11.
enum Enum2 : unsigned short;     // Illegal in C++11, because Enum2 was previously declared with a different underlying type.
```

So if your compiler supports forward-declared enums, you can turn on C++0x/C++11 support change your code to:

```
class Printer;
enum Printer::States : char;
class Printer {                  // choose one of monitor or cormonitor
    States taskStates[];
  public:
    enum States : char { Starting = 'S', Blocked = 'B', Unblocked = 'U', Finished = 'F', // general
          Napping = 'N', Awake = 'A',             // Santa
          Working = 'W', NeedHelp = 'H',          // elf
          OnVacation = 'V', CheckingIn = 'I',     // reindeer
          DeliveringToys = 'D', DoneDelivering = 'd', // Santa, reindeer
          Consulting = 'C', DoneConsulting = 'c' // Santa, elves
    };
    Printer();
    void print( unsigned int id, States state );
    void print( unsigned int id, States state, unsigned int numBlocked );
};
```

If not, you can't scope your enum to the class. You could make a separate namespace and use a typedef to get similar syntax:

```
class Printer;

namespace printer {
    enum States : char { Starting = 'S', Blocked = 'B', Unblocked = 'U', Finished = 'F', // general
          Napping = 'N', Awake = 'A',             // Santa
          Working = 'W', NeedHelp = 'H',          // elf
          OnVacation = 'V', CheckingIn = 'I',     // reindeer
          DeliveringToys = 'D', DoneDelivering = 'd', // Santa, reindeer
          Consulting = 'C', DoneConsulting = 'c' // Santa, elves
    };
}

class Printer {                  // choose one of monitor or cormonitor
    States taskStates[];
  public:
    typedef printer::States States;

    Printer();
    void print( unsigned int id, States state );
    void print( unsigned int id, States state, unsigned int numBlocked );
};
```

And then outside of the Printer class, before the Printer class definiton has been seen, you'll need to refer to States as printer::States rather than Printer::states. After the Printer class definition has been seen, you can refer to States as Printer::States as usual (because of the typedef).

Alternatively, if you drop the namespace you just refer to them as States.